# Strapi custom email template

Tags: html-email, strapi

I'm using nodemailer for email submission and running from my localhost. I have email services created manually in the following dir `/api/email/services/Email.js`

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'example.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: 'user',
        pass: 'password',
    },
});

module.exports = {
    send: (from, to, subject, html) => {
        const options = {
            from,
            to,
            subject,
            html
        };
        return transporter.sendMail(options);
    },
};
```

So then I can use it like `strapi.services.email.send(from, email, subject, html);`

Usually, I write my html template in the code line `const html = '<p>Email testing</p>'` to be passed in the email services. But I don't want to do this for every email submission from different controllers.

So, I created a html template in `/config/email-templates/custom-email.html` and tried to call it like `const html = path.join(__dirname + '/../../../config/email-templates/custom-email.html');`.

When I run it, the email can be sent successfully but it cannot render the html. Instead of a rendered html, it's showing the full path of the `custom-email.html` as the email message. Is this method possible to achieve in strapi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the path to the file, you need to pass the actual content. In the first case `const html = '<p>Email testing</p>'` , you are actually passing the content , but in the second case you are passing the file path.

Modified send method could look something like below:

```
send: (from, to, subject, htmlpath) => {

  const readHTMLFile = (path, callback)=> {
    fs.readFile(path, {encoding: "utf-8"}, function (err, html) {
        if (err) 
            return callback(err);
        else 
            return callback(null, html);
    });
  } 

  readHTMLFile(htmlpath, function(err, html) {
      const options = {
        from,
        to,
        subject,
        html
    };
    return transporter.sendMail(options);

  }); }
```

Comment: I see, thank you! Do you mind if I ask one more question of how if I want to pass variable to the html there?

Comment: Oh nvm, I will make a different post. Again, thank you!

Comment: You can use handlebars library for that... A sample where you can pass emaillink , firstName and year to your email template    ``const template = handlebars.compile(html);const replacements = {emailLink: emailLink,firstName: firstName,year: new Date().getFullYear()};const emailTemplate = template(replacements); ```

Comment: And then you can pass the emailTemplate to the `options` inside your send method.